# Is it possible to nest values based on key column in AppSheet?

Tags: mobile

I have a table connected to AppSheet that has a column called "Names" there are many values that have the same name with different information. Is there anyway in AppSheet to have the user tap on one name and have all of the values show up that have the same Customer name. Essentially grouping.

---

I know there is a community on Google Plus for AppSheet but it doesn't seem very active my question has been sitting on the site for weeks. If anyone needs more clarification please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very clear what you are trying to achieve, but you can correct me if I'm wrong.

You want in the Inline view of any given Customer, to have a list of referenced values.

You can do this with a SELECT() function. In Data > Columns > + "Virtual column" 
In the "App formula" input add your function.

For example: `SELECT( myTable[myColumn], [Name] = [_THISROW].[Name])`

What this does:
List all values from column named "myColumn" in table "myTable"
where "Name" has the same "Name" as this row,

https://help.appsheet.com/expressions/functions/select

If you want to list not only values but a list of referenced rows from another table, you should use REF_ROWS.

For example `REF_ROWS("myOrdersTable", "orderCustomer")`

What this does: list all rows from table named "myOrdersTable" where column named "orderCustomer" has the same value as the unique KEY of this row.

REF_ROW virtual columns are generated automatically when you give a "REF" type to any column. In this example if you go to Data > Columns > "myOrdersTable" and change the type of "orderCustomer" to "REF" with "ReferencedTableName" to "myCustumerTable", a virtual column with list of referenced rows will be generated in  "myCustumerTable" table after you save.

https://help.appsheet.com/data/references/references-between-tables

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for, do you know if it is possible to add a little logo to the top of the screen where the navigation is? I saw some other sample apps they had, include a logo instead of text with the name of the app. Sorry for being a little of topic, its just very difficult to receive any sort of support for AppSheet.

Comment: It looks like the have removed this option, you can PM me on telegram @kloshar4o. Dont forget to up vote if my answer was helpful